# Modal form only works after refresh

Tags: ruby, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I have a modal form in my application that is spawned by a link in the nav bar. The form seem to only work when the page has been refreshed, if I access a page from a link it wont work until I refresh the page.

Here is my form in aoolication.html.erb:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h1>New Update</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
        <div class="container">
          <p>What have you been working on?</p>
            <p>
              <%=f.label :title %> <br>
              <%=f.text_field :title %>
            </p>

            <p>
              <%=f.label :body %> <br>
              <%=f.text_field :body %>
            </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <%= f.submit %>
        <%end%>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

From looking into it I've found it could be caused by malformed HTML, but I can't seem to find anything that ould be causing it.

Any help with fixing this would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: The only thing I can see is the `<br>`. self-closing tag would be `<br />`. Also, have you looked at the generated code?

Comment: That doesn't seem to make a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix it by placing the entire body in form for tags